# Nestled loops with IF statements c#

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, boolean

Trying to solve a simple c# question and I did but my teacher wants me to do it with a nestled loop instead of with a boolean.

Problem: Show all numbers from input number that is divisible by 3 and 7. If no number is found show "No number found".

How i solved it with bool:

```
Console.WriteLine("Put in a number: ");
int nummer = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

bool FoundLegitNumber = false;

for (int i = 1; i <= nummer; i++)
{ 
    if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 7 == 0)
    {
        FoundLegitNumber = true;
        Console.WriteLine($"The number {i} is evenly divisible by 3 and 7");
    }
}

if (!FoundLegitNumber)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Didnt find any number...");
}
```

How I'm trying to solve it with a for loop:

```
Console.WriteLine("Put in a number: ");
int nummer = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

for (int i = 0; i <= nummer; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; i >= j; j++)
    {
        if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 7 == 0)
        { 
            Console.WriteLine($"The number {i} is evenly divisible by 3 and 7");
        }
        else if (j == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Didnt find any number...");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I know, it doesnt make any sense but I cant figure out how to solve it. I know that I want to give J + 1 if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 7 == 0) was not true.

Comment: Interesting to require a nested loop when one isn't needed; wouldn't make a habit of that. Are you sure they didn't ask for a nested `if`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure yeah, but just out of curiosity how would one do a nested if in this instance?

Comment: You already did a nested `if` in your first example (when you called the `if` statement within the `for` statement)

Comment: Oh sorry, i mean how would do a nested If the right way and solve the problem? In other words, do a nested if and only show "Didnt find a number" once if it didnt find one at all.

Comment: Your first solution seems fine to me

Answer (score 0):

If you want a method that involves a nested `for` without distorting the basic problem, maybe you could add a dividers array like this:

```
int number = 21;
int[] dividers = new int[] { 3, 7 };

for (int i = 0; i <= number; i++)
{
    bool matchAllDividers = true;
    for (int j = 0; j < dividers.Length; j++)
    {
        if (i % dividers[j] != 0)
        {
            matchAllDividers = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (matchAllDividers)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The number {0} is evenly divisible by all dividers".FormatWith(i));
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The number {0} is not evenly divisible by all dividers".FormatWith(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But I do think this is too complicated for me, only a week into coding and dont really understand everything that this do.

Comment: I can add some comments if you want to.  You could also validate with your teacher because otherwise I don't really see how a nested for would help in this particular case.